# How deteck swipe up correctly

Tags: android, touch, swipe, ontouchlistener

I have a video viewing screen. at the touch down event, I stop the video, at touch up resume. However, I encountered a difficulty - I need to swipe up and open the video settings window, while the video should be paused.

I handled the down and up events correctly - but now when I process swipe up, I get problems.
According to the documentation, down is called first, then swipe, then up - as a result, I get events that I don't need during the swipe. How do I track that it is a swipe and at the same time ignore down and up?

i have code to try

```
    override fun onTouch(view: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                touchAction(TouchEvent.TOUCH_START) //callback touch start
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                touchAction(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END)  //callback touch end
            }

            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                val lastTouchPosition = lastDownTouchPosition ?: return false
                val deltaX = lastTouchPosition.x - event.rawX
                val deltaY = lastTouchPosition.y - event.rawY

                if (deltaY.absoluteValue - deltaX.absoluteValue > 1.5 && deltaY > 0) {
                    swipeUpAction() //callback swipe up
                }
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Can i filter ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP  in ACTION_MOVE ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to introduce a SimpleOnGestureListener(), see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures) (examples in Java **and** Kotlin).

Comment: and how will he help me?

he does the same thing I do with my hands - only it's a wrapper.